# moment.js | check isBefore getting confused with date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm currently working with a project where I need to find if a time in `HH:mm` is before another time.

I am using moment time zone and setting the time zone globally to UTC.

The date which I am comparing is: `2020-09-02T00:00:00.0000+00:00`

I am running a check where I am doing the following:

```js
const example = '2020-09-02T00:00:00.0000+00:00'
const time = moment(example)
const timeStart = moment('08:00', 'HH:mm')

console.log(time.isBefore(timeStart))
```

The console log returns a result of `false`.

The reason I believe is that the `timeStart` is evaluating to the current day, so it's failing due to the date being in the future. I need to stop moment from comparing the date, is there a way to do this?

What I am trying to achieve is something of the following

```js
'00:00:00'.isBefore('08:00')
```

```js
const time = moment('2020-09-02T00:00:00.0000+00:00')
const timeStart = moment('08:00', 'HH:mm')

console.log(time)
console.log(timeStart)

console.log(time.isBefore(timeStart))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *isBefore* compares the entire date and time, not just the time. The above uses a UTC timestamp but compares the local time, is that what you want? Or should it compare the UTC time?

Comment: It should compare with UTC if possible

Comment: Please put additional information in the OP.

Comment: I have added it, although I am setting UTC globally so it shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with moment.js by converting the timestamp to a moment object, then cloning the object and setting its time to the required comparison time. That way you're always comparing times on the same date.

To keep everything as UTC, use *utc*. E.g.

```js
let ts = '2020-09-02T00:00:00.0000+00:00';
let d = moment.utc(ts); // Invoke UTC mode
let time = '08:30';

let [h, m] = time.split(':');
let e = d.clone().hours(h).minutes(m).seconds(0).milliseconds(0);
console.log(d.format() + ' is before\n' +
  e.format() + '? ' + d.isBefore(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can compare just the time with plain JS fairly easily:

```js
/**
 * Compare a time to just the time part of a
 * Date, all using UTC.
 *
 * @param {Date} date - date to compare
 * @param {string} time - time in HH:mm format
 * @returns {boolean} true if time in date is before time passed to function
 */
function isTimeBefore(date = new Date(), time) {
  // Get time value for start of UTC day
  // Copy date so don't affect original
  let dayStart = new Date(+date).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  // Convert the time to milliseconds since midnight
  let [h, m] = time.split(':');
  let ms = h*3.6e6 + m*6e4;
  // Compare to the date's milliseconds elapsed since midnight
  return ms > (date - dayStart);
}

// UTC timestamp
let ts = '2020-09-02T00:00:00.0000+00:00';
// Convert to Date
let d = new Date(ts);
// local time
let time = '08:30';
console.log('UTC: ' + d.toISOString() + '\nis before ' + time + ' UTC? : ' + isTimeBefore(d, time));
```

The built–in parser should generally be avoided, however the above uses it to convert the timestamp to a Date because it's about the only supported format that is reliably parsed by browsers in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
const time = moment('2020-09-02T00:00:00.0000+00:00')
const timeStart = moment('09:00', 'HH:mm')    
time.isBefore(timeStart) //returns true
```

returns true to me.

Comment: If you run  my script in the question you can see that it returns false.

Comment: The OP's date is before "today", the issue is to compare the time irrespective of the date.